# Cannot set text in a textView from a for-loop in Android?

Tags: android, textview

I am trying to set some text from a for-loop in my `textView`.
I have this `List`: `List<List<String>> movies` and the `for-loop` looks like this:

```
int i = 0;
for (List<String> listMovies : movies) {
     i++;
     txtViewResult.setText("Movie " + i + " - " + "Number of actors: " + list.size() + "\n");
     txtViewResult.setText("  Actors:\n");
     for (String s : listMovies) {
          txtViewResult.setText("   " + s + "\n");
     }
}
```

My `textView`:

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            android:id="@+id/tvResult"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:maxLines="200"
            android:paddingStart="15dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"/>
```

My problem is I am getting just the last line of the `for-loop` **(the last actor)** in the `textView`?!!!

I have put `android:singleLine="false"`, `android:maxLines="200"` **(just in case)** and I am using; go to the new line `\n`. Nevertheless, I am not getting what I want.

Any idea(s) why I am getting this? Did I miss some `attribut` for the `textView`?
Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to concatenate text before you set it in textView. Now your textView has last name of actor becouse that line is called as last.

```
     txtViewResult.setText("   " + s + "\n");
```

Try to do something like this:

```
String myText = ""
for (List<String> listMovies : movies) {
     i++;
     myText += ("Movie " + i + " - " + "Number of actors: " + list.size() + "\n";
     myText += "  Actors:\n";
     for (String s : listMovies) {
       myText += "   " + s + "\n";
     }
}
txtViewResult.setText(myText)
```

Comment: I get it ;) and thanks. Better is to use `StringBuilder` class, then `append()`